# Why does OS X mangle the playback of this MP3?

Tags: itunes, audio, quicktime, mp3

[Here's an MP3](http://75thtrombone.com/links/stack-exchange/example.mp3) I have.

- My iPhone plays it back with no problems.
- VLC on OS X plays it back with no problems.
- iTunes plays it with annoying bleeps and bloops, some kind of errors or artifacts that are very noticeable at the beginning of the track.
- Other OS X playback methods, like QuickTime Player or Quick Look, have tiny skips/gaps in the playback, in the same places where iTunes has the error bleeps.

The MP3 has a 32 kHz sampling rate instead of 44.1 kHz; is that the problem? When I use an OS X conversion tool like [XLD](http://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html), the tiny gaps are in the output, no matter what kind of conversion I do. Is the problem actually with the MP3 or with OS X/Core Audio?

This happens on multiple Macs running OS X 10.11.3 using iTunes 12.3.2.35.

Comment: I'm no audio expert however based on the tests I did I could replicate the issue as expressed under different OS X and iTunes version until I changed the sampling rate by streaming it to a file at 44.1 kHz using VLC at which point it played without issue everywhere.  FWIW looking at magnified waveform output in Audacity and the original file I see nothing that would account for the noise.  So while not a highly scientific analysis by any means nonetheless it looks like native OS X methods of playing including, `afplay`, iTunes, etc. don't like the 32 kHz sampling rate.